# Permission denied :try again later error in ssh

Tags: windows, powershell, ssh, server, openssh

I have installed openssh on windows server machine, I tried to make ssh connection.

I see permission denied error only for particular and for other users under the same group the ssh cmd works

I running the following

ssh username@ IP of the machine

I think there is some problem in ssh generated for this particular user, how to solve this problem?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking questions like this on [su] or [sf]. When you do, you should show the exact ssh command which you are running, any associated config from .ssh/config or similar files, and the exact output that you're getting. It'd be helpful to run ssh with the "-vvv" option to print debugging output and include that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in SSH functionality in Windows 10 (since v1809) does not seem to support all possible characters in a password. Yeah, unfortunately this is the truth. You can reproduce the error for example with the character `§`. A user that can login successfully with a password like `password`, will not be able to login with a password like `pa§§word` using the built-in SSH client on Windows 10 up to this date (2020-03-23).

You may check if your users are using "too complex" passwords. Pure ASCII should work though, so there are still some special characters left for complex passwords.